# CTE is a Best Practice instead of temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

"Common.XXX" datatable is creating into temp table. But it creates some performance issue. How can I remove temp table ? OR what is your advise? What is the best practice? Using CTE is better that temp table. Am I right? How can I improve below the performance of query?

```py
CREATE PROCEDURE [Common].[GetXYZ]  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    BEGIN TRAN;  
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #xxx;  

    SELECT TOP (1)  
        *  
    INTO #xxx  
    FROM Common.Import WITH (UPDLOCK)  
    WHERE State = 1  
    ORDER BY Id;  

    UPDATE Common.Import  
    SET State = 2  
    WHERE Id IN (  
                    SELECT Id FROM #xxx  
                );  

    UPDATE #xxx  
    SET State = 2;  

    SELECT *  
    FROM #xxx;  
    COMMIT;  
END;
```

Comment: Where is the performance penalty? Do you by any chance call this procedure once for every row? I'm not sure if this is an oversimplified version of your procedure but I'm sure you can rewrite it to be shorter and most likely faster too.

Comment: Why even use a temporary table for that?

Comment: you can do this whole thing in a single statement

Comment: Is your `Common.Import` table indexed by any chance?

Comment: Using a CTE or subquery, and an `OUTPUT` clause would be a far better idea here. There's no need for 4 statements when it could be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way would be as below. This avoids a load of unnecessary operations in your current code (I am assuming `Id` is unique)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT TOP (1) * 
    FROM Common.XXX WITH (UPDLOCK)  
    WHERE State = 1  
    ORDER BY Id
)
UPDATE CTE
SET  State = 2
OUTPUT INSERTED.*;
```

Comment: I recommend to the OP, however, that as this is a pre-compiled object using `*` is a bad idea; they should replace it with the column names. Otherwise if the definition of `Common.Import`  is changed it's unlikely the SP will behave as they expect.